# How do I use PLINQ to process chunks of an array

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, plinq

I need to take a large array of doubles, and process it in chunks using a processor intensive function.

My original array is extremely large, about 200MB of doubles of signal data.

I need to take it in chunks of 5000 doubles each, process those with some very processor intensive math using a function that returns a single double.  Each of those functions results is needed to create an ordered array that is used later.

I *think* this would be optimal for parallelism using PLINQ, but I am not quite sure how to go about doing it.

The naive implementation that I wrote looks like this :

```
        var processedList = new List<double>();

        var chunk = new List<double>;
        foreach (var rawSample in drop.RawSamples)
        {
            chunk.Add(rawSample);

            if (chunk.Count == 5000)
            {
                // Do long processing here
                processedList.Add(LongProcessingFunction(chunk));

                chunk.Clear();
            }
        }

        // Do something later with the list of processed values.....
```

So, where do I start with PLINQ?  I need to be able to do the long, intensive function using all the cores of the processor.

I see there is a Take(n) function for IEnumerable.....  Can I use this?

Can I use AsParallel here?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use `Take(5000)` repeatedly, put the processing of this chunk in a new `Task` and [`WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) tasks.

Comment: I want to get away from managing my own thread pool.  I think creating a few thousand tasks and then waiting on them all won't be very efficient.  I think there ought to be some plinq syntax that will do this for me?

Comment: If your scheduling isn't too complicated, I think it's fine to use the provided mechanisms from [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321263.aspx), perhaps with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you're dealing with this amount of data, you should avoid processing it element by element, if you can. In your code, you could do that by iterating integers in 5000 increments and using something like [`Array.Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft).

Or, even better, don't do any copying at all, let `LongProcessingFunction` accept an array (or `IList<T>`, or `IReadOnlyList<T>`, if you're on .Net 4.5; but using an interface does have some overhead) and an offset into that array.

If you then want to make your code parallel, you can use [`ParallelEnumerable.Range()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.range) with [`AsOrdered()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413357) (which is necessary to have the results in the correct order) and `Select()`:

```
double[] result = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, drop.RawSamples.Length / chunkSize)
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(i => LongProcessingFunction(drop.RawSamples, i * chunkSize))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement a partitioner on your indexed source which will partition your source into chunks of 5000 elements. Each of them can then be processed paraallelly using `AsParallel`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IList<double> rawData =  [Your raw data here];

        IList<double> result =
            rawData
                .Partition(5000)
                .AsParallel()
                .AsOrdered()
                .Select(chunk => LongProcessingFunction(chunk))
                .ToList();
    }

    private static double LongProcessingFunction(IList<double> chunk)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Partition<T>(this IList<T> source, Int32 size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(source.Count / (Double)size); i++)
        {
            yield return new List<T>(source.Skip(size*i).Take(size));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Custom partitioners can increase efficiency, but they're not meant to implement basic logic.

Comment: In your code, you're not actually implementing a [partitioner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768), so I think another name for your method would be better. And if I understand the question correctly, you also need to add `AsOrdered()` to your query.